# combining mbtiles and getZoom to visualize with Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mbtiles

I have exported MBTiles as single file for every zoom scale. Now I can add map manually call them with mbtiles.php server. But I want to accumulate it in one and get the mbtiles file on zoom scale change with getZoom() method. I trying with following code but its not changing mbtiles files with zoom level change. I am trying with the following JS codes.

```
var zoomIntr ="zoom_10";

    var mapURL ="maps/mbtiles.php?db="+ zoomIntr +".mbtiles&z={z}&x={x}&y={y}";

    var streetMap = L.tileLayer(mapURL, {
            tms: true,
            maxZoom: 17,
            minZoom: 05
    });
    var map = new L.Map('map', {
      center: [51, 0],
      minZoom: 5,
      maxZoom: 17,  
      zoom: 10,
      attributionControl: true,
      zoomControl: false,
      layers: [streetMap]

    });  

map.addControl(L.control.zoom({position: 'bottomright'}));

var zoomScale = map.getZoom();
map.on('zoomend', onZoomend);
function onZoomend(){
        if (zoomScale===5) {zoomIntr="zoom_05";}
        else if (zoomScale===6) {zoomIntr="zoom_06";}
        else if (zoomScale===7) {zoomIntr="zoom_07";}
        else if (zoomScale===8) {zoomIntr="zoom_08";}
        else if (zoomScale===9) {zoomIntr="zoom_09";}
        else if (zoomScale===10) {zoomIntr="zoom_10";}
        else if (zoomScale===11) {zoomIntr="zoom_11";}
        else if (zoomScale===12) {zoomIntr="zoom_12";}
        else if (zoomScale===13) {zoomIntr="zoom_13";}
        else if (zoomScale===14) {zoomIntr="zoom_14";}
        else if (zoomScale===15) {zoomIntr="zoom_15";}
        else if (zoomScale===16) {zoomIntr="zoom_16";}
        else if (zoomScale===17) {zoomIntr="zoom_17";}
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are exporting different mbtiles files for each zoom level, rather than exporting all zoom levels in one mbtiles file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply changing the `zoomIntr` value doesn't update the value associated with `mapURL`.  To illustrate, try this:

```
var zoomIntr ="zoom_10";
var mapURL ="maps/mbtiles.php?db="+ zoomIntr +".mbtiles&z={z}&x={x}&y={y}";
var zoomIntr ="zoom_17";
console.log(mapURL);
```

Furthermore, simply changing mapURL won't force the map base layer to change.  To do this, you'd have to remove the existing layer and create an entirely new layer using `map.addLayer(...)` and `map.removeLayer(...)` ([see docs](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-addlayer)).

It's possible, but you might have minor performance problems creating and removing layers every time you zoom to a new zoom level.  Are you sure you can't just have one .mbtiles file with all zoom levels?